# How to update libssl.so on very old devices?

Tags: updates, https

I tried asking this on xdaforums but did not get a useful answer so I thought I would try here.

I've got some very old devices (used as wifi-only) that are starting to have issues connecting to (some but not all) modern websites. One runs FroYo, another Ice Cream Sandwich. They are both rooted and I have ADB working on both of them. Some of the sites in question are using very little javascript, so even the old browsers that can be installed on them used to connect okay until VERY recently. I have succeeded in updating the root certs on both of these, which has helped with some web sites, but not all. The troublesome change seems related to certificate updates on some of the websites. Where they used to be using TLS1.1 and certs based on SHA1, they have changed to TLS 1.3 and SHA256, which these old devices don't support.

I should add that this is not just about browsers. There are similar issues with other apps like email, VoIP callling, XMPP clients, weather apps, pretty much anything that needs network access. There are also issues connecting to certain specific (but not all) wifi networks, I suspect a similar cause for this too.

So, I want to update the version of libssl.so used on these devices. I have found some instructions on how to compile this, which looks like it will be an adventure unto itself (and maybe a separate topic for further questions).

One helpful detail about devices this old, they do not yet use dm-verity, so at least I will not need to bother about dealing with that.

Before I get too far down the compilation rabbit hole, assuming I manage to get it compiled correctly, is it really as simple as just dropping the replacement files into /system/lib ? Do I also need to update libcrypt.so at the same time? Or are there other items I would also need to update? Has anyone done this before, short of rebuilding the entire ROM?

Comment: Older versions of libssl are not API compatible to newer versions, which means that you cannot simply replace libssl. The actual applications must be compiled against the new lib and maybe changes are needed in the applications too.

Comment: Your main problem is most likely not libssl but Chrome respectively the WebView component which I think is no longer updated for these old Android versions. As far as I know Chrome and WebView contain their won SSL/TLS stack and don't make use of libssl from Android. Only apps that open a TLS connection by Java/Kotlin (DEX) code make use of Android libssl.

Comment: The Google recommended way handling TLS issues on older devices (I think 4.0+ is at least supported) is using a special crypto provider that comes with Google Play Services.  Apps can enable this if necessary by one code line. For details see e.g. https://code.mendhak.com/tls-13-old-android-devices/ and https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/security/ProviderInstaller

Comment: @Steffen - That wasn't what I wanted to hear... but then life is like that sometimes.  :-( Thanks for the clarification, anyway.

Comment: @Robert - I have tried looking on apkpure.com and apkmirror.com for old versions of both Chrome and WebView. There is Chrome 42 that could work for the IceCreamSandwich tablet, but nothing suitable for the FroYo device. The only WebView versions I could find all need at least Lollipop. The other problem is that the FroYo device is so old it does not use the ARMv7a instruction set, only ARMv6, and I could not find any of these things in that variant.

Comment: The article about the conscrypt provider seemed promising, saying it could work all the way back to FroYo... but then the app he posted on F-Droid requires at least 4.1 Jellybean, so I don't see how to use it, even assuming other apps were compiled with it in mind.

Comment: While the question title might be an [XY-problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/241919), I'm honestly curious if the *TLS stack* can be upgraded by end-users without resorting to a custom ROM/Android update.

Comment: An alternative solution might be to proxy the modern sites on a PC/local server so that the older browsers can access them, see: [Proxy (or other solution) that can allow vintage browsers (before HTTPS era - with no or weak SSL/TLS support) to connect with HTTPS websites?](https://superuser.com/q/1487553)

Comment: @Morrison - I've been tinkering with a proxy for my old XP desktop having similar issues, in that case it is a locally run proxy (one of the ones described at https://msfn.org/board/topic/183352-proxhttpsproxy-and-httpsproxy-in-windows-xp-for-future-use/ ). Do you (or anyone else) know of something like that to run on old androids? I would want it to run *on the old devices* so it could be helpful when I am not at home.

Comment: @ILikeOldStuff I really wouldn't be running old (Froyo released in 2010) devices outside. While you may want to keep things around, legacy bugs like [Stagefright](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stagefright_(bug)) may exist in those versions. Additionally modern sites are using modern HTML/CSS which require modern webkit engines which now run on multi core CPUs. Proxy PC is doing heavy lifting. More FYI, [Project Crosswalk](https://github.com/crosswalk-project/crosswalk) existed for consistent webkit on 2.x-4.x hw. You'll have to find docs on archive.org as site is gone and web standards change.

Comment: @Morrison - For my specific use case(s), Stagefright is actually a non-issue. Its main transmission vector is MMS, Bluetooth and possibly videos, and none of those apply to these two devices.  Neither device has EVER had any phone number or cellular carrier account, so there is no path for MMS to be delivered through.  A wifi-only device (one of which does not even have any cellular nor bluetooth radio hardware) simply can't receive those things, and I uninstalled YouTube, Facebook, Twitter, etc many years ago.

Comment: Since I don't put any private data on these devices, there is simply nothing to steal, thus very little risk. They each have a dedicated email account (NOT from google) that is not shared with anything else, and the VoIP passwords are device specific too, so even losing these is little more than an inconvenience since I would simply use my desktop (which can use an assortment of passwords which the devices do not have) to cancel those device passwords. And no, I do not do any internet banking on these devices (or any other android no matter how new) so malware can't steal what isn't there.

Comment: The few websites I want to work also have very little javascript, so that is less of a problem, also changing browsers can help too. The biggest hurdle is lack of support for modern encryption prevents connections from happening.

Thanks for the Crosswalk link, there is a lot of stuff there and will take me a while to digest it.